# CakePHP4 input field SOMETIMES causes 403 Forbidden Error

Tags: mysql, forms, input, cakephp, http-status-code-403

This is weird, at least for me. A text form input field works, sometimes. When it doesn't I'm sent to a 403 Forbidden Page, "You don't have permission to access this resource." is all it gives me.

The most recent error:

If I enter "Double steel structural plate culvert and has thousands of 1 inch bolt heads.
Installed in 1984.
Outlet fill is 3 feet, Inlet fill is 4 feet, center fill is 5 feet.
Corrugation span is 6.25 inches, rise is 2 inches
Inlet requires repair prior to lining, invert failing, at least at the ends.
Lots of sediment to remove, we'll need Raymond, maybe two days?
Minimal flow at time of survey.
Will require 5 foot weir dams and small pumps.
Good equipment parking, no lane closure or traffic control should be necessary." **it works fine**.

If I enter "Double steel structural plate culvert and has thousands of 1 inch bolt heads.
Installed in 1984.
Measures 14.5 feet wide and 8.5 feet high, one is 175 feet long, the other is 185 feet long.
Outlet fill is 3 feet, Inlet fill is 4 feet, center fill is 5 feet.
Corrugation span is 6.25 inches, rise is 2 inches
Inlet requires repair prior to lining, invert failing, at least at the ends.
Lots of sediment to remove, we'll need Raymond, maybe two days?
Minimal flow at time of survey.
Will require 5 foot weir dams and small pumps.
Good equipment parking, no lane closure or traffic control should be necessary." **I get the 403 error.**

The only difference is the line "Measures 14.5 feet wide and 8.5 feet high, one is 175 feet long, the other is 185 feet long."

Apache version: Apache/2.4.51

PHP version: 7.4.23

MySQL version: 10.2.41-MariaDB

Directories are 755, files are 644

database table field type is text, Collation is utf8mb4_unicode_ci

```
$validator
    ->scalar('details')
    ->requirePresence('details', 'create')
    ->notEmptyString('details');
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It's not something like your login session happened to time out between the first one and the second?

Comment: I don't think so, I can "Back" to the page, change the input and submit successfully. After writing this post it later worked, and other (unconnected) 403 errors occurred. It appears I have a gremlin somewhere...

Answer (score 1):

Closing this question until I can better state it. I'm not longer sure of the problem so it's unreasonable to expect someone to answer it.

Comment: Good idea. Hopefully you can get some more insight into issue and solve it on your own.